# Disabled Input Field

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, tags, jstl, input-field

I was trying to disable a input field in my input.tagx. This my code:

```
<form:input id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" readonly="${readonly}" class="form-control" />
```

I tried putting **disabled** in it, like this:

```
<form:input id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" readonly="${readonly}" class="form-control" disabled/>
```

But it's an error. It's my first time using tagx. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have this in the header of input.tagx:

```
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="disabled" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify if this field should be enabled" />
```

and this is in my view.jspx:

```
<field:input field="pvId" id="c_ph_com_smesoft_hms_domain_Person_pvid" disabled="pvId"/>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @mhasan Multiple annotations found at this line: -Attribute "disabled" has no value -Attribute name "disabled" associated with an element type "form:input" must be followed by the '=' character.

Comment: just check what your ${disabled} is resolving to what value, as per XHTML your expression for disabled should be disabled="disabled"

Comment: also I noticed you are missing type attribute in your input field

Comment: @mhasan Just add other information on my question Sir.

Comment: It has found multiple attributes cause multiple annotations of multiple attributes show errors because you have unassigned attribute values.